# Base on home work

Tags: american-english

Which one is right I wanna used was or where it were a puppy or it was a puppy I think it were a puppy am I right I need some help am kinda baffle thank you

Comment: *Was* is past tense for first and third person singular, *were* is used with the others, You need third person singular:  *it was a puppy*

Comment: @StoneyB unless, say, it's in a conditional of type: "if it were a puppy...", with the given fragment we can only assume (and you justly assume the most likely)

Comment: @msam Quite so; but as near as I can make out OP's sentences are indicative.

Answer (score 1):

If I have intuited your question correctly you're asking when to use "were" vs when to use "was".

> **were** is *plural*; "The dogs *were* puppies".
>
> **was** is *singular*; "The dog *was* a puppy".

Comment: kudos. you understood his question. it took me 10 minutes to quit.

Comment: *Were* is plural AND 2nd person singular. *Was* is 1st and 3rd person singular.

Comment: @StoneyB So, Rover was taken from us too soon; "You were the kind of puppy every dog owner wants"? It's difficult to write for a dog(s) in the second person.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Well, very few dogs can read. But my boss frequently speaks to her dogs in the 2nd person.